# How to call a function without pressing a button

Tags: c++, sleep

I have a homework assignment to create a game. So I have created a game that generates random numbers, displays them, then after a few seconds the numbers disappear and the user has to enter them in descending order. The game works fine and all the output is correct... but the problem is I have created different functions for creating numbers, arranging them, accept.. and I have to press the enter key a few time each time a function call comes.

Is there a way by which these functions get called without pressing any key to make the program work without pressing the enter key?

Comment: You created a game? Any sample code you would like to share with us? Because by saying that you created a game, you actually didn't say much.

Comment: I've added the [tag:sleep] tag to your question, you should look at previous questions with that tag for some clues

Comment: Most likely you organised your code in such a way that it waits for user-input (several times) before it continues with the next stage.

Answer (score 0):

Pulled from [Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/c-c-capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pr)

> That's not possible portably in pure C++, because it depends too much
>   on the terminal used that may be connected with stdin (they are
>   usually line buffered). You can, however use a library for that:
>
> 1. conio available with windows compilers. Use the function _getch() to
>      give you a character without waiting for the enter key. I'm not a
>      frequent windows developer, but i've seen my classmates just include
>      conio.h and use it. See conio.h at wikipedia. It lists getch, which
>      is declared deprecated in Visual C++.
> 2. curses available for linux, compatible curses implementations are
>      available for windows too. It has also a getch function. (try man
>      getch to view its manpage). See Curses at wikipedia.
>
> I would
>       recommend you to use curses if you aim for cross platform
>       compatibility. That said, I'm sure there are functions that you can
>       use to switch off line buffering (i believe that's called "raw
>       mode", as opposed to "cooked mode" (look into man stty)). Curses
>       would handle that for you in a portable manner if i'm not mistaken.